Regular Expression to check for the pattern plus excluding the input string to be empty spaces
I have the following Regular Expression to check for the input string pattern. However, it didn't return false when the input string is space only. Could those experts give me a hand?
^[a-zA-Z0-9\s,!_/+\-*@~#$&^=%.]*$


Success: abc def, abc.
Fail:  .


You have \s in your character set, which includes all whitespace characters.

I suggest trimming leading and trailing spaces before calling the regex if possible - it will make the regex simpler and the data cleaner
